# Select2 Default selected from optgroup

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, haml, jquery-select2

Need some help here. I inherited this code and I am not 100% on what needs to be done here but I need to set the default selected item to be the first group/first option instead of the `data-placeholder`. 
I tried using `ng-init` but I wasn't able to get it to work. 
How can I achieve this with the below code?

```
<div ng-repeat='searchField in searchFields.device'>
    <select data-placeholder='Search Field' ng-model='searchField[0]' ui-select2>
        <option value=''></option>
        <optgroup label='FooGroup1'>
            <option value='foo_option1'>foo_option1</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label='FooGroup2'>
            <option value='foo_option1'>foo_option1</option>
            <option value='foo_option1'>foo_option1</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
....
```

**ACTUAL HAML**

```
%div(ng-repeat="searchField in searchFields.message")
  %select(ng-model="searchField[0]" ui-select2 data-placeholder="Search Field" ng-init="searchField[0] = ")
    %option(value="")
    - devices_optgroup.each do |group, attrs|
      %optgroup{label: group}
        - attrs.each do |attr, label|
          %option(value="#{attr}")= label
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<option>` element allows for an optional `selected` attribute. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option):

> **selected**
>   If present, this Boolean attribute indicates that the option is initially selected. If the  element is the descendant of a  element whose multiple attribute is not set, only one single  of this  element may have the selected attribute.

So if you want to select the first element of the first `<optgroup>` you can do something like this:

```
<select data-placeholder='Search Field' ng-model='searchField[0]' ui-select2>
    <option value=''></option>
    <optgroup label='FooGroup1'>
        <option value='foo_option1' selected>foo_option1</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label='FooGroup2'>
        <option value='foo_option1'>foo_option1</option>
        <option value='foo_option1'>foo_option1</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: How would this be written in the HAML since the options are defined after the build OR how can I specify the index for `selected`

Comment: You could try something like this: `%option{:value => attr, :selected => label == "foo_option1"}= label`